# Does the white cement between tiles absorb water

Tags: tile, roof, floor, water-damage, cement

Our roof is covered with white color cooling tiles and we have cemented the gaps between the Tiles with white cement.

Whenever the tank in the terrace overflows , it falls on the terrace tiles,runs on top of the tiles and goes out through rain drain on the terrace to the ground.

I'm wondering whether the white cement in the terrace can absorb the water.

As far as I understand , cement or white cement or concrete shouldn't absorb the water. It's the nature of bricks to absorb hence we're plastering that with cement.

Can someone clarify this please ?

**Update:**
Which is the best option for binding tiles ?

- White cement
- Caulk
- Grout

IMO white cement is great as it's stronger than Grout But I heard adhesive strength of grout is higher while caulk is perfect but it's expensive.

Comment: I guess white cement will absorb the water